# Google Tag Manager - dataLayer.push() with pagination, keep on pushing?

Tags: knockout.js, pagination, google-tag-manager

We're using proper pagination and fetching products which we bind to our view using KnockoutJS. All working fine and dandy.

Our company wants to record the impressions for each of these products, so we can easily push each product array into the `dataLayer` (on the `ecommerce` block).

Is it common practice to keep adding and adding to this GTM `dataLayer` object which, if you are on a product list page with client side filtering/sorting/narrowing, this `dataLayer` array is going to get enormously bloated, and is likely to have an impact on browser memory usage.

Is the push() significant? Or could we simply assign the new product list array to the first index in the dataLayer each time? Would that be recorded correctly by GTM?

Comment: Do you need to have all the products from the begining at the same time in your dataLayer or only the current page?

Comment: Only the current page at a time, but we need GTM to 'record' each product impression as and when people page through each page of products.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to keep on pushing to the dataLayer array, in the sense that all of the products in the current DOM should be tracked as impressions. If you don't track all of the current impressions you cannot track the position when they are clicked on. The Google Tag Manager data model will be updated each time you push, merging the product impressions in the new push into whatever it had for the initial page load.

To prevent the array getting too large I decided to clear the dataLayer on the ajaxSuccess before the new dataLayer.push

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {

    /* Clear dataLayer - prevents array getting too large */
    dataLayer.length = 0;


    dataLayer.push({
      'ecommerce': {
      'impressions': [
       {
         'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
         'id': '12345',
         'price': '15.25',
         'brand': 'Google',
         'category': 'Apparel',
         'variant': 'Gray',
         'list': 'Search Results',
         'position': 1
       }]
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Google limits the number of items in the dataLayer, so at some point it starts freeing memory.

Duplicate of: [Google Tag Manager dataLayer Is Never Cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721224/google-tag-manager-datalayer-is-never-cleared)

The limit was 300, but in my testing the cap seems to be increased to 1000.