# Google Tag Manager dataLayer Is Never Cleared

Tags: google-tag-manager

In a single page app, I register "page views" to Google Analytics and track other events using the Google Tag Manager.  I keep pushing events to the dataLayer and everything is working fine.  The only issue is that the array is never cleared.  It can get 100's of values in it during a session.  Is it ok to set a timer to clear a pushed event 30 seconds after it is pushed?  Or am I being overly sensitive about something that is not that big of a deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the dataLayer structure is capped at 300, so this is not a concern.  When more than 300 items are pushed, the oldest item is removed.